# AS3: currentFrame & stop ();

Tags: actionscript-3

So, my next problem. Sorry for asking so much, but my teacher doens't respond. So, this doesn't work. The stop command doesn't seem too respond, but i don't get an error either. I know i miss a bracket, but my function isn't finished. Due to copy and paste the place of the brackets have shifted a bit.

```
function Knipperen (event:TimerEvent):void 
{
    if (event.currentTarget.currentCount == 3 && geknipperd < 3) 
    {
    geknipperd ++;
    timer.reset();
    timer.start();
    trace (geknipperd);
    gotoAndPlay(1);

    if (currentFrame == 13) 
    {
        stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Nobody is going to answer you questions like these, basically because they are unanswerable. We cannot see anything from your code. Where is this code from? Timeline? Class? Does the class extend movieclip? And yes, you do miss a bracket and would be nice if you filled it in. Also, please consider NOT using capitalized first letter for function names. You are also sending the playhead to frame 1 and then you check whether you are at frame 13.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go to frame 1.

```
gotoAndPlay(1);
```

And here you check if the frame is the 13th.

```
if (currentFrame == 13) 
{
    stop();
}
```

The condition failing is very much expected. I see you are using the trace command. Using it more liberally or adding breakpoints will help you with these trivial problems.